# Anyway to force NUnitlite run in the main thread?

Tags: c#, nunit, nunit-3.0

In NUnit/Nunitlite 3.13 ( or any other version of NUnit 3.x), is it possible to force the tests to run in main thread?

I've already decorated my test as `Apartment(ApartmentState.STA)`, and yet, it still runs in a separate thread, as shown below:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
[TestFixture, Apartment(ApartmentState.STA)]
public class MetaClass
{
    [Test]
    public void RunA()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(1,1);
    }
}

[Apartment(ApartmentState.STA)]
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string directoryPlugin = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        string directoryReportUnit = Path.Combine(directoryPlugin, @"ReportUnit");
        Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryReportUnit);
        string fileInputXML = Path.Combine(directoryReportUnit, @"Report-NUnit.xml");


        string[] nunitArgs = new List<string>
        {
         
            "--trace=verbose" // Tell me everything
            ,"--result=" + fileInputXML
              ,"--workers=-1" //with or without this parameter, a parallel worker thread is still used 
        
        }.ToArray();


        new AutoRun().Execute(nunitArgs);
    }
}
```

Note that with or without the parameter `"--workers=-1"`, a parallel worker thread is still used.

Answer (score 0):

NUnit's `ApartmentAttribute`, used with `ApartmentState.STA` as you are doing, forces threads to run in the single threaded apartment. In addition, it has the side effect that the NUnit dispatcher will only run one one such test at a time... i.e. it uses the Non-Parallel test worker thread. However, it has nothing to do with what thread runs in the STA. So don't use that attribute expecting to influence the use of threads.

How the framework uses threads is controlled by the `--workers` option on the command-line. I'm not 100% sure, because this varies according to the version of the framework you are using, but I believe that `--workers=-1` will get you closer to what you want because it eliminates use of the parallel dispatcher entirely.

Comment: "varies according to different versions"-- how can they be inconsistent? I am using the latest version 3.13 btw

Comment: See updated question. Note that with or without the parameter `"--workers=-1"`, a parallel worker thread is still used.

Comment: I originally wrote the code so that `--workers=-1` bypassed the parallel dispatcher. I haven't worked on the framework for a long time but based on what you are seeing, I think the feature may have been removed.